# Toggle "Plain Text Mode" when writing in email with Gmail, with a shortcut

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

We can toggle "Plain Text Mode" when writing in email with Gmail by clicking on the 3 little dots (bottom right), and select the menu item.

Can we configure a keyboard shortcut for this? I haven't found it in Gmail > Settings > Customize shortcuts.

Would there be a hack (involving a custom made javascript code to run in the console or Autohotkey) for this?

Comment: AHK script can do this easily

Comment: @user0 Not so easily, I tried `!^+p:: Send {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}...` to reach the 3-dots menu and toggle the item, but then CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+P sends the email instead... A good working solution would be welcome!

Comment: well, every time I need an AHK script I go to https://discordapp.com/invite/tPGdSr2 and ask those folks there. they are always very nice and their knowledge is tremendous.